# how to create a list of lists and add item to it

Tags: python, svm

I am using SVM for training and I have to add my lists to X[]. For example,

```
 X=[]
 m = [1,1,1]
 n = [2,2,2]
 l = [3,3,3]
```

...
I want to make X as [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]...]

I have tried

```
print X.append(m)
```

but it did not work. The result is None.
What should I do?

Comment: It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.

Comment: Basically, Stack Overflow is for questions about problems you can point to, where you can say *this isn't working*. Right now you're asking for something much broader, and Stack Overflow isn't a good site for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X.append(m)` is correct, except that it modifies `X` in place *but does not return it* (it always returns `None`).

If you examine `X` after calling `append()`, you'll see that it has changed accordingly.